# Нужна запятая?

Tags: запятая

Все ребята бегают поют?

**Обновление**

Не знаю, как поступить в этом случае)

```
Вокруг гремит салют,
Падают снежинки,
Ребята бегают-поют,
За окном сияют льдинки.
```

Comment: @luxerios, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Обычное перечисление (разных) действий. Безусловно: запятая.

Вопросительный знак перекочевал, видимо, по ошибке? А то можно и ещё один вставить по типу: Кто Вы? Доктор Зорге?

И ещё,- при нынешнем отношении к Ё всякое бывает,- может фраза и такой быть: "Всё ребята бегают-поют", где действия объединены отношением к ним.

Comment: Не знаю, как поступить в этом случае)<br />
Вокруг гремит салют,
Падают снежинки,
Ребята бегают-поют,
За окном сияют льдинки.